# What bookmarking app for local server?

Tags: bookmarks

Is there a lightweight bookmarking app I could run on my server, that you could recommend?

Nice features would be importing browser bookmarks, marking bookmarks private/public, simple api for adding new bookmarks and openid authentication.

EDIT: I've went with scuttle: it's basically drop-in replacement for delicious.

Answer (score 2):

I've also found [Scuttle](http://sourceforge.net/projects/scuttle/). I'll evaluate listed apps these days and share impressions.

Comment: +1 for scuttle, Its a great application similar to delicious

Answer (score 1):

I have used [SiteBar](http://sitebar.org) they offer it as a service but the software is [open source](http://sitebar.org/downloads.php).

Answer (score 1):

[SemanticScuttle](http://semanticscuttle.sf.net/) is a fork of Scuttle, has more features and is actively developed.
I use it at home and at work, and we integrated it with our Active Directory/LDAP for authentication.

Comment: +1 Cool - I've used Scuttle before, but didn't know about this fork.  Thanks!